# tcolorbox: wrong column width and space between columns

Tags: margins, tcolorbox

I don't know why but I can't manage to get equal width columns, with a correct column skip using `tcolorbox` if the columns does not fill the whole page. Here is a picture:

If the columns fill the whole page, I don't have any trouble, the columns have the same size and have the same spacing:

[image: correct behavior]

However, if I reduce the size, the boxes does not have the same width, and the spacing is clearly not equal to 3mm:

[image: wrong behavior]

Do you know why?

Thank you!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tcbitemize}[nobeforeafter,
    raster columns=2,
    raster rows=2,
    % Works when full width
    % raster width=\textwidth,
    % raster height=\textheight,
    % Does not work when smaller width
    raster width=.5\textwidth,
    raster height=.5\textheight,
    % ----
    raster row skip=3mm,
    raster column skip=3mm]%
    \tcbitem[raster multirow=2,blankest]%
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1,raster rows=2]%
      \tcbitem[colback=red]{A}
      \tcbitem[colback=red]{B}
    \end{tcbitemize}%
    \tcbitem[raster multirow=2,raster multicolumn=1,colback=red]{C}%
  \end{tcbitemize}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: The title `Tcolor` is misleading. You mean `tcolorbox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner `tcbitemize` environment needs an additional parameter, *viz*.,

```
raster width=\textwidth
```

Why? The outer `tcbitemize` environment specifies both `raster columns=2` and `raster width=0.5\linewidth`. The *total* width of both columns taken together is `0.5\textwidth`, and each column's width is thus `0.25\textwidth` (abstracting from the fact that there's 3mm of whitespace between the blocks).

Unless these parameters are overridden explicitly, they apply to the inner `tcbitemize` environment as well. The length variable `\textwidth`, by design, adjusts dynamically. To make the single column in the inner `tcbitemize` environment take up the full available width (which is `\textwidth`, as `\textwidth` has been adjusted), we need the additional option `raster width=\textwidth`.

The full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tcbitemize}[nobeforeafter,
    raster columns=2,
    raster rows=2,
    raster width=.5\textwidth,
    raster height=.5\textheight,
    raster row skip=3mm,
    raster column skip=3mm]
    \tcbitem[raster multirow=2,blankest]
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1,raster rows=2,
                       raster width=\textwidth]% <-- new
      \tcbitem[colback=red]{A}
      \tcbitem[colback=red]{B}
    \end{tcbitemize}
    \tcbitem[raster multirow=2,raster multicolumn=1,colback=red]{C}
  \end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative for this construction could be `tcbposter` library introduced in `tcolorbox v4.10`.

A `tcolorbox` poster is an unbreakable array of boxes which provides easy/flexible options to place boxes with different widths and heights.

Two examples with `tcbposters` are shown in [Creating this poster layout using minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378438/1952) or [Dynamic box size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387491/1952)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tcbposter}[
    poster = {
%       showframe, 
        columns = 2,
        rows = 2,
        height = .5\textheight, 
        width = .5\textwidth, 
        spacing=3mm},
    boxes = {colback=red}
    ]
    \posterbox{column=1, row=1}{A}
    \posterbox{column=1, row=2}{B}
    \posterbox{column=2, row=1, rowspan=2}{C}
  \end{tcbposter}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I may use it for some stuff, thank you!