# BAposter headerbox without title

Tags: baposter

I'm using the BAposter class to prepare a poster and I would like to have one of the boxes without title.

If I leave the title parameter blank:

```
\headerbox{}{name=myBox,...}{myText}
```

Then it still displays the header of the box.

Any ideas on how to hide the header of the box? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `baposter` boxes always declare a title part. You could leave it empty and use the background color of text part, but the space is always there. If you need nontitled boxes and you are starting with your poster a good alternative could be `tcbposter` (from `tcolorbox` package), it uses a boxes placement system similar to `baposter` and you can use nontitled boxes. Some examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378438/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387491/1952 and a [tutorial](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox-tutorial-poster.pdf).

Comment: With `tcbposter` you'll have to manually select font size. It doesn't scale automatically like `baposter` does.

Answer (score 2):

The height of the `posterbox` header is given by the `boxheaderheight` key. If no `posterbox` header is required, set the `boxheaderheight` to `0em` as one of the keys passed to the `posterbox` environment.

More generally, all the keys available in the `poster` environment are available to the `posterbox` environment. This permits extensive customization of individual `posterbox`es. This is illustrated by changing the `posterbox` header colour (`headerColorOne`) from `blue` to `green` and the font color for the header from `white` to `black` for the fourth `posterbox`.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper]{baposter}

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
  grid=false,
  columns=2,
  colspacing=4.2mm,
  headerheight=0.10\textheight,
  background=none,
  eyecatcher=false,
  %posterbox options
  headerborder=closed,
  borderColor=red,
  headershape=rectangle,
  headershade=plain,
  headerColorOne=blue,
  textborder=rectangle,
  boxshade=plain,
  boxColorOne=white,
  headerFontColor=white,
  headerfont=\color{white}\large\bfseries\sffamily,
  textfont=\normalsize\sffamily,
  linewidth=1pt
} 
{}
{Title}
{\textsc{Author}}
{}

\begin{posterbox}[name=box1,column=0,column=0,row=0,span=1]{Title}
This box has a header. The height of the box header is given by the key \texttt{boxheaderheight}.
The default \texttt{boxheaderheight} is 2em.
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[name=box2,column=0,below=box1,span=1,boxheaderheight=0em]{}
This box has no header. Set the height of the box header with the key \texttt{boxheaderheight=height}, 
where \texttt{height} is some height measure like 4em. Add the key to the options passed
to the \texttt{posterbox} environment.
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[name=box3,column=1,row=0,span=1,boxheaderheight=0em]{}
Another box with no header.
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[name=box4,column=1,below=box3,span=1,headerColorOne=green,
                  headerfont=\color{black}\large\bfseries\sffamily,bottomaligned=box2]{Title}
This box has a header. The default \texttt{headerColor1}, given in the keys to the \texttt{poster} 
environment is changed from \texttt{blue} to \texttt{green}. The bottom of the box is aligned 
with the bottom of \texttt{box2}.
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Contrary to your result, if I run your code, the boxes remain open at the top.